# jQuery Waypoints Not functioning on initial scroll

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using the script below along with the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#documentation) to fade elements into 100% opacity when they are centered 50% (or 75%) in the browser window. The code seems to be working pretty good except the elements don't seem to initially fade in. When I scroll down and then back up it seems to be triggering them then.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#feature').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   var targetOpacity = direction === "down" ? 1 : .25;
   $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": targetOpacity });
}, {
   offset: '50%'
});

$('#footer').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   var targetOpacity = direction == "down" ? 1 : .25;
   $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": targetOpacity });
}, {
   offset: '75%' 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout $.waypoints('refresh') to trigger the actions on the page load

Comment: Didn't seem to fix the issue.